# How to create pandas columns and fill with values according to values in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
text           sentiment
asdasda        positive
fsdfsdfs       negative
sdfsdfs        neutral
dfsdsd         mixed
```

**and I want this outupu:**

```
text           positive     negative     neutral      mixed
asdasda           1            0           0           0
fsdfsdfs          0            1           0           0
sdfsdfs           0            0           1           0
dfsdsd            0            0           0           1
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) but before that you need to set `column "text"` as index and after getting result you need to rename all columns `sentiment_positive` to `positive` , `sentiment_negative` to `negative`, ...

```
import pandas as pd
# df <- your_df
res = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('text')
                     # rename column sentiment_positive to positive , 
                     # rename column sentiment_negative to negative , ...
                    ).rename(columns = lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
print(res)
```

---

```
          mixed  negative  neutral  positive
text                                        
asdasda       0         0        0         1
fsdfsdfs      0         1        0         0
sdfsdfs       0         0        1         0
dfsdsd        1         0        0         0
```